# How do I rotate a Google map?

Tags: google-maps

Sometimes I wish to rotate a map. I can do this with [scribblemaps](http://www.scribblemaps.com), but it is more of a drawing tool then a plain map view.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Google Maps has a set of features in [Labs](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2010/02/introducing-google-maps-labs-your.html) just like GMail does.

- Click the green labs icon:  [image: labs]
- Enable Rotatable Maps:  [image: Rotatable Maps]
- Save changes
- In the maps, click the Rot Map button in the upper right of the map.
- Rotate the map using the dial in the upper left of the map.  [image: dial]

Comment: Does a similar feature exist in the current version of Google Maps? Where even is the Labs option?

Comment: [No more labs for google maps anymore](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112934/where-are-labs-for-google-maps-desktop-are-they-gone) This answer has been 100% obsolete since 2011

Answer (score 5):

This is how you do it as of ~November 27, 2019:

1. In the bottom left corner, hover over the "Layers" box and then click the "More" box:
   [image: "More" box]
2. Select the "Satellite" map type and check the box for "Globe view":
   [image]
3. Now, the `Ctrl` + `Shift` + Drag method should work.

Comment: I could not get this to work in Chrome, Brave, Opera, or Safari.

Comment: If you are using a Mac, I imagine you would need to use the Command key (`⌘`) rather than the `Ctrl` key.

Answer (score 4):

**NOT WHAT YOU "SHOULD" USE**

That has already been answered... but...

You could always try the [Aviary Screen Capture Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncgcgghbabbopfcpgcjpfffdgnbadegf).

It will allow you to rotate anything in your browser.

[Look what it did to this page! http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4572500/4572980_2bc4_625x625.jpg](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4572500/4572980_2bc4_625x625.jpg)

Comment: But does it keep the labels the corect way up so they are skill easy to read?

Comment: Aviary have withdrawn the service so it's a moot question I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

1. Trigger "Satellite" mode on the bottom left of the screen.
2. Press Ctrl+Shift and drag with your mouse to rotate.

If you click on "Map" mode it will go back to the original position, though.

**Option #2:** Try a different map style from https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com and rotate it on Photoshop or similar.

**Option #3:** Try https://www.openstreetmap.org

**Option #4:** Try https://www.maptiler.com/maps/#positron//vector/16.07/-43.929654/-19.936152/149.60. Rotate the map with right click and drag.

Comment: for my purposes, maptuiler ended up being exactly what i needed! thank you!

Comment: Looks like the Ctrl+Shift+Drag (or any other combinations of Ctrl, Shift, and Alt) doesn't work anymore...