# Where are Labs for Google Maps desktop? Are they gone?

Tags: google-maps

Are the lab section for the desktop version of Google Maps gone? Googling only returns old results, although I found this link https://maps.google.com/?showlabs=1 but it does not seem to make any difference.

Specifically I am looking for the lab that allowed the user to show maps with east or west, instead of north, up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Google shut down most of their experimental labs features in 2011](https://www.digitaltrends.com/android/saying-goodbye-to-google-labs-a-look-back-at-our-favorite-experiments/).

The only ones that still remain are for Gmail.